# vb exporting the contents of a textbox into a txt file on the PC with different names for each file automatically

Tags: vb.net

I have found the following code on another website - a print function that exports the code in the textbox into a txt file in the c drive of my PC.

When trying to alter it to make it suit my code it, doesn't work and I was wondering what's wrong with what I've got?

The code is as follows ..

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\test.txt", True)
file.WriteLine("Here is the first string.")
file.Close()
```

I then changed the "here is the first string." to the contents of the textbox (which is also a list) and also changed the location of the file to make it able to make a new file every time based on the date and time of the PC running it like as follows.

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\" + OrderType.txtCustPhoneNumber.Text + " " + Today + " " + TimeOfDay, True)
    file.WriteLine(txtBoxOrder.Text)
    file.Close()
```

The variables of `Today` and `TimeOfDay` being the date and time according to the system and the textbox "OrderType.txtCustPhoneNumber.Text" being a textbox that individualises different files if the times and dates clash.

This is because the software will be run on two PCs that share the same storage.

Comment: What is the question? If it is clashing then append Environment.UserName to the file name.

Comment: Please, use punctuation marks. It's impossible to read.

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Make sure the generated filename is valid - e.g. if your Today variable  is a date with a slash in it you may get unexpected results. Also if your TimeOfDay has a colon (:) in it that is a definite no-no!

Comment: sorry the question must not have been clear enough, i've tried to edit the code that  ive found to export the file onto the c drive with a different file name each time with the name of the file being (OrderType.txtCustPhoneNumber.Text + " " + Today + " " + TimeOfDay). if the TimeOfDay variable consists of a colon which isnt allowed, is there a way to edit it out or is the time an unusable variable in this case???

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Dim filename as String

filename = "C:\" & OrderType.txtCustPhoneNumber.Text & "_" & Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_hhmmss")

file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filename, True)

You can apply a format to the timestamp. My personal preference is to build filenames into strings and to not use spaces. YMMV.